# Server Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, next.js, fetch-api

I need help to understand how to fetch external data using server-side rendering with the `getServerSideProps` method. My real problem is with the search itself, more specifically with the type of data that is returned and how to deal with it. I am not an experienced JavaScript programmer, so I think this is more of a JavaScript issue than next.js.

This is where I fetch inside `getServerSideProps`:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const url = `https://...`;
  const options = {
      < header info...> };
  
  const res = await fetch(url, options);

  const data = await res.json();

  const orders = data.list;   **// here is where the problem might be** 

  return { props: { orders } };
}
```

Here where I render from `getServerSideProps`:

```
const ListOrders = ({ orders }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {orders.map((o, i) => (
        <h3 key={i}>{o.orderId}</h3>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here the object that I fetch. The data that interests me is the list.

```
{

"list":[...]

"data1":[]

"data2":{...}

"data3":{...}

}
```

I would appreciate any help on that.

Comment: How / where are you calling `getServerSideProps` and where are you passing orders to the `ListOrders` component? Also, are you sure that `data` contains a value? You can try to `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` to see if that shows anything in the browser's console (ex: Chrome DevTools).

Comment: Hi Brandon. This code is actually running in the backend using a method form Next.js for rendering server side props. No possibility for console.log.

Answer (score 1):

this error shows data `orders` is undefined. First thing when you map, in case you dont have any orders array, you have to add a guard to your code, so your app wont break.

```
 <div>
      {orders && orders.map((o, i) => (
        <h3 key={i}>{o.orderId}</h3>
      ))}
    </div>
```

this is called short circuiting, `orders.map` will run if `orders` is defined.

Since you make an api request. make sure that api server allows your app to do fetcing. Normally you cannot fetch data from external server, unless it allows you.

`console.log()` does not run inside `getServerSideProps()`. It is important that you always examine the data that you are fetching. Instead of passing `orders` pass whole data `const data = await res.json()` as prop. `return { props: { data } }`

Now inside the component, `console.log(data)` see if you ever fetched any data, if yes examine the structure.

Comment: Thanks Yilmaz. I appreciated your help. Thinks are getting cleared now. At least now I know I am getting error 400 - Bad Request. Here is my other post where I put out the code. If your could take a look and see if you con help me I would be happy with that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66433023/nextjs-getserversideprops-error-400-bad-request

Answer (score 0):

You should check structure of orders data before you start using it
U can only map on arrays
The error say that there no variable named undefined

For eg if we call the function and assign result to a variable

```js
let orders =  getServerSideProps()

//The data structure of orders variable be like this 
/*
orders = {  
           props : {
               orders :{ data1 : [  ], data2 : [ ] }
                 } 
  */               } 
// If you map on data1 you need to access like this 
orders.props.orders.data1.map(eachdata=>{
// stuff that you want to do here
})
```

Comment: Hi mohammed. I did that mapping orders.list according to the data structure. I got the same issue so that's why I tried to assign data.list to orders before returning props. In both cases, I received the same error.